Infant 4 months Traveling to India from Nepal
my daughter turned up 5 months earlier this month. She was born in Japan.
Being a Nepalese citizen, we are planning to travel to India via Nepal. Could someone help to let me know what document is required for my infant while traveling.
Thank you.

She will definitely need a passport. What exactly route are you planning to fly?

In my understanding a Nepalese citizen can travel to India without passport if she/he has a valid ID. I will fly from KTM-GAU.

You cannot board a flight from Japan to Nepal without a passport.

We can board a flight from Japan to Nepal without passport with a valid travel document from the Embassy.

Non-passport travel documents are typically intended for emergency use only. Why not just get a full passport from the Embassy?
